# How fix Windows10 doesn't remember windows position on desktop

Tags: desktop, windows-10

It's the first time(in all Windows versions) that I notice this BIG problem.
Windows on desktop(except Chrome) continue to open in a different position without remember the last one.
A fix?

Comment: I've only noticed it with VLC, which I have auto-launch at startup. It was putting the window where it wanted, not where I put it. Fix was… launch, move window, quit, launch. Test by reboot… Fixed.

Comment: Nope my friend :( this isn't a fix. It's very annoying mostly with Windows Explorer, it continues to open according to a precise pattern

Comment: Tried the 'set all folders like this one' trick? Same as in Win7, just a bit harder to find, In View menu/options, I think - not on a Win machine right now

Comment: Nada! I think a registry hack can be the solution but I don't know what to do precisely...

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas - wish you luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a proper fix, but [this workaround](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/launching-and-positioning-an-application-on-startup/?ID=a0f16c60-9c49-486f-a300-fe37589fb9d8) may help. In short:

- Get [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/).
- Go to DisplayFusion's settings.
- Open the 'Triggers' tab.
- Add a trigger with:

  - Event: Window Created
  - Process Filename: <whichever program you want in a fixed positions>
  - Add an action: Move Window to Specific Size and Location
- Press OK.
- Press Apply.

Also works for issues like [this one](https://old.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6g8tbs/get_edgesnapped_windows_to_remember_their_position/) where Windows 10 will move windows close to the monitor edges 10 pixels inward after reopening it.